# Azure notification hub The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure, notifications

This has been working until now, we were able to use the connection string of the format `Endpoint=sb://`

But now we're getting

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel exception on the line

```
var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle.FcmToken, 100);
```

Nothing has changed in code or hub settings.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this by [updating the target .net framework to 4.7+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/232661/azure-notificaiton-hub-exception-could-not-create.html) or by forcing tls 1.2 by:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```